# IIS7 Not sending Intermediate SSL Certificate

Tags: iis, ssl, certificate

We have a GlobalSign Domain certificate for our domain. I've installed the certificate into IIS and added the GlobalSign Domain Intermediate certificate to the Intermediate certification authorities for the **local computer**

It seems that IIS is not sending through the intermediate certificate (causing an error in firefox), just the domain certificate. I've verified this with OpenSSL and also various websites including GlobalSign's own health checker.

Looking In IIS, I can follow through the chain and each certificate is "ok", without the option to install any indicating they already are.

Any ideas on what may be wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally managed to find a solution. For some reason, It must not of bound correctly in IIS. Removing and rebinding the certificate in IIS fixed the issue.

Comment: It's even easier: no need to remove the current binding or whatsoever. In IIS: 1) go to bindings 2) select https binding 3) "edit" 4) click "ok" button. Repeat for every https binding - so no need to remove the current certificate or something like that. The intermediate certificates can be checked on Windows with "DigiCert® Certificate Utility for Windows" https://www.digicert.com/util/

Comment: Julian's technique above showed me that the server was actually missing the intermediate certificate; once that was installed, still had to follow Julian's steps above, and the issue was resolved.