# Intermediate certificate not sent to clients?

Tags: ssl, certificate, iis

I have installed intermediate certificate on server according to all tutorials for IIS, that is:
"Certificates MMC snap-in, you choose computer store, you'll have the option to place the intermediate certificates"

When I access the service on server machine the certificate chain is correct (root cert -> intermediate cert -> my cert). However when I'm trying to access this page from client site I see only my cert in certificate chain (meaning there's no intermediate cert).

If I understand correctly (from what I've read in different topics here) I should install intermediate cert only on server machine and it should be sent to clients, no need to install intermediate cert on client machines? Is this right?

Comment: I have used DigiCertUtil at client machine to check if the server actually sends this cert, and it turns out it does. I don't understand whywhen I access page in bowser cert chain is incomplete...

Comment: This question would probably be more appropriate over at ServerFault. I've flagged for a moderator to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out two problems occured here:
1) need to refresh bindings in IIS:
[IIS7 Not sending Intermediate SSL Certificate](https://serverfault.com/questions/238206/iis7-not-sending-intermediate-ssl-certificate)
2) need to clear certificate cache in IE8

Thanks anyway. Please move to ServerFault if possible.